# How to use Get File Properties REST API for Azure Files Storage using Python

Tags: python, azure, http, http-headers, azure-files

I am trying to create a Python script which will utilize both the Python SDK for Azure and REST API's in order to extract information for files in my Azure Files Storage Account.

I am using the SDK to access the files in storage and get there names. Then using the name I want to be able to have a REST API call to get the file properties, specifically the Last-Modified property. I try to access the last modified property using the SDK but it always returns None for some reason.

I want to use the last modified date to determine if it has been more than 24 hours and if it has then I want to delete the file. I am not sure if it possible to set some sort of auto delete after a certain period property on the file when i first create and upload it to azure. If there is then this will solve my problems anyhow.

I have posted the code I am using below. When i try to make the HTTP request I get the error "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

```
    import datetime
    import requests
    import json
    import base64
    import hmac
    import hashlib
    import urllib
    from azure.storage.file import *

StorageAccountConnectionString = ""
fileshareName = "testFileShare"
storage_account_name = "testStorage"
storage_account_key = ""
api_version = "2018-03-28"

        file_service = FileService(connection_string=StorageAccountConnectionString)
    listOfStateDirectories = file_service.list_directories_and_files(fileshareName)

    for state_directory in listOfStateDirectories:
        print("Cleaning up State Directory: " + state_directory.name)
        if(isinstance(state_directory, Directory)):
            listOfBridgeDirectories = file_service.list_directories_and_files(fileshareName, state_directory.name)
            for bridge_directory in listOfBridgeDirectories:
                if(isinstance(bridge_directory, Directory)):
                    print("Cleaning up Bridge Directory: " + bridge_directory.name)
                    path_to_bridge_directory = state_directory.name + "/" + bridge_directory.name
                    listOfFilesAndFolders = file_service.list_directories_and_files(fileshareName, path_to_bridge_directory)

                for file_or_folder in listOfFilesAndFolders:
                    if isinstance(file_or_folder, File):
                        name_of_file = file_or_folder.name

                        # Get the time of the current request
                        request_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

                        string_to_append_to_url = fileshareName + '/' + path_to_bridge_directory + '/' + name_of_file
                        # Parse the url to make sure everything is good
                        # string_to_append_to_url = urllib.parse.quote(string_to_append_to_url)

                        string_params = {
                            'verb': 'HEAD',
                            'Content-Encoding': '',
                            'Content-Language': '',
                            'Content-Length': '',
                            'Content-MD5': '',
                            'Content-Type': '',
                            'Date': '',
                            'If-Modified-Since': '',
                            'If-Match': '',
                            'If-None-Match': '',
                            'If-Unmodified-Since': '',
                            'Range': '',
                            'CanonicalizedHeaders': 'x-ms-date:' + request_time + '\nx-ms-version:' + api_version + '\n',
                            'CanonicalizedResource': '/' + storage_account_name + '/' + string_to_append_to_url
                        }

                        string_to_sign = (string_params['verb'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['Content-Encoding'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['Content-Language'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['Content-Length'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['Content-MD5'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['Content-Type'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['Date'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['If-Modified-Since'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['If-Match'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['If-None-Match'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['If-Unmodified-Since'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['Range'] + '\n'
                                          + string_params['CanonicalizedHeaders']
                                          + string_params['CanonicalizedResource'])

                        signed_string = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(storage_account_key), msg=string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()

                        headers = {
                            'x-ms-date': request_time,
                            'x-ms-version': api_version,
                            'Authorization': ('SharedKey ' + storage_account_name + ':' + signed_string)
                        }

                        url = ('https://' + storage_account_name + '.file.core.windows.net/' + string_to_append_to_url)
                        print(url)


                        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
                        print(r.content)
```

NOTE: Some of the directories will have white spaces so I am not sure if this is effecting the REST API call because the URL will also have spaces. If it does effect it then how would i go about accessing those files whose URL's will contain spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to access the last modified property using the SDK but it always returns None for some reason.

Not all of SDK API and REST API will return the `Last-Modified` property in the headers of the response, which include REST API [`List Directories and Files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-directories-and-files) and Python SDK API [`list_directories_and_files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.fileservice.fileservice?view=azure-python#list-directories-and-files-share-name--directory-name-none--num-results-none--marker-none--timeout-none--prefix-none--snapshot-none-).

I tried to reproduce your issue using SDK, as the code below.

```
generator = file_service.list_directories_and_files(share_name, directory_name)
for file_or_dir in generator:
    if isinstance(file_or_dir, File):
        print(file_or_dir.name, file_or_dir.properties.last_modified)
```

Due to the `list_directories_and_files` method will not return any properties in the `File` object, so the `file_or_dir.properties.last_modified` value of the code above is `None`.

The REST APIs [`Get File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file), [`Get File Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file-properties), [`Get File Metadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file-metadata) and the Python SDK APIs [`get_file_properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.fileservice.fileservice?view=azure-python#get-file-properties-share-name--directory-name--file-name--timeout-none--snapshot-none-), [`get_file_metadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.fileservice.fileservice?view=azure-python#get-file-metadata-share-name--directory-name--file-name--timeout-none--snapshot-none-) will return `Last-Modified` property in the headers of the response, so to change the code as below to get the `last_modified` property to make it works.

```
generator = file_service.list_directories_and_files(share_name, directory_name)
for file_or_dir in generator:
    if isinstance(file_or_dir, File):
        file_name = file_or_dir.name
        file = file_service.get_file_properties(share_name, directory_name, file_name, timeout=None, snapshot=None)
        print(file_or_dir.name, file.properties.last_modified)
```

Ofcouse, to call the REST API is as same as to use SDK API. However, to build a SAS signature string is easy to make mistakes and not friendly for reading code.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Yeah i realized that when using the File object of the list operation, the last modified value is always None. But using the get_file_properties of the file service class, the value is accessible. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @alihasan Could you mark it as answer if it works for you?

Comment: @PeterPan This works works with ".last_modified" but not with ".content_type" or ".type". Does it need a different method than "get_file_properties"?